# SQL Developer Migration repository Error - Error in the SQL script execution. Try to remove the repository before to create one

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to migrate a Mysql 5.6.21 database to Oracle 11.2.0.1 using SQL Developer.

So I create my schema like this:

```
CREATE TABLESPACE repo datafile '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/RAC/repo_01.dbf' size 1024M autoextend off;
CREATE USER repo IDENTIFIED BY repo DEFAULT TABLESPACE repo TEMPORARY TABLESPACE temp; 
GRANT connect, resource, create session, create view to repo;
```

Then Create a connection in SQL Dev.

And when I issue Associate Migration Repository option get the message "Error in the SQL script execution. Try to remove the repository before to create one."

Any help?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your syntax looks good to me. Did the above DDL generate any errors when you executed it?

Comment: Thank you, No, the error is in SQL Developer. I changed the version to Sql Developer 4.1 but now I have the following error when Done Migration Wizard:

ORA-01400: Can't perform insertion
NULL in ("MIGRATIONS", "MD_PROJECTS"."ID")

Any Idea?

Comment: Whole other issue. I recommend asking another question with sample data, screenshots, and the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

grant all privileges to repo;

[sql error on script execution. try deleting repository before creating repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31697203/sql-error-on-script-execution-try-deleting-repository-before-creating-repositor)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).