# sql error on script execution. try deleting repository before creating repository

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to migrate my mysql databse to oracle.
I have followed the migration demo from this url http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/migration/connect-step-mysql-1946352.html

but I got this message when try to associate migration repository

`sql error on script execution. try deleting repository before creating repository`

I am using 
**Oracle Sql Developer v 4.1.1.19**
**Oracle express edition 11g releas 2**

see the picture bellow what I have tried step by step

step1: Creating a user named **migration_repo**

[image]

step 2: Creating connection named **migration_repo** using **migration_repo** user
[image]

step3: try to associate migration repository
[image]

step4: executing the command
[image]

but after few seconds I got this error message.
[image]

Now. how can I solve this? what I have done wrong?

Comment: Warning: if you would simply try to create the repository again you'd receive a misleading message that it is already created. In this case you wouldn't be able to execute the migration, and would get a confusing ORA-01400 error about trying to insert a null value in a not null field. If one is trying to migrate from an external database and is getting an ORA-01400 error, Oxalc's answer bellow can help.

Answer (score 26):

I had the same problem, this was solved changing the GRANT statement with...

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES to {migration-name} identified by {migration-name};

just be aware to remove privileges after migration tasks.