# Migration from SQL server to Oracle - Capture failing

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle, migration

I am trying to migrate a database from SQL server to Oracle.
Following the procedure documented here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/migration/connect-sqlserver-1945229.html

Source DB: SQL Server 2012 Standard Edition with Service Pack 2 (x64)

Target DB: Oracle 11g

OS: Windows 2012 x64

Following the procedure listed above I have installed SQL Developer, the jdbc driver, the oracle database.
I created the migration repository as listed in the procedure. 
The connection to the sql server source database via sql developer works.
The connection to the migration repository account in oracle works.

When I try to perform any meaningful migration there is always an error as a popup window saying: 
"migration actions have failed check the migration reports for details. : Capture Enterprise Capture Capture failed. Refer to MIGRLOG table in the repository for details"

- The MIGRLOG table is empty.
- The logs in the output folder are empty in most tries and  not helpful in the other tries.

How can I find out why the capture failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be solved by granting more privileges to the migration repository. I found this from here:

[sql error on script execution. try deleting repository before creating repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31697203/sql-error-on-script-execution-try-deleting-repository-before-creating-repositor)

Thanks to Oxalc!