# Migrate SQL Server Database to Oracle using SQL Developer on same system not work

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a SQL Server database with name test3 that have 1 table with name A that have 1 column with 5 rows, I want migrate to Oracle but it gives an error before I enter Oracle password as shown as.

[image]

Error message:
[image]

Note: I grant all privileges to [migration-name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31797706/12780274) (`MyCon`) but not work.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES to {migration-name} identified by {migration-name};
```

My Oracle version: 19C and Oracle SQL Developr version=19.2.206 .

Comment: can you make sure the user also has quota on the tablespace? also if you have just a basic table, you can right-click on it and say 'copy to oracle'

Comment: how can i sure user also has quota on the tablespace? When I copy to Oracle that failed

Comment: ALTER USER X QUOTA UNLIMITED ON Y - where X is the migration repo user and Y is the tablespace you've assigned them (probably defaults to DATA or SYSAUX.

Comment: Copy to Oracle Failed - if you want to chase that down, start a new question, provide the details.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith your mean I use this: `ALTER USER MyCon QUOTA UNLIMITED ON SYSAUX `  ;    ` tablespace 'DATA' does not exist`

Comment: @thatjeffsmith Thanks work for me. Please post your answer so I can choose it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most common reason I've seen the Migration Repository from being created correctly no newer instances of Oracle is that the user associated with the schema lacks QUOTA on the user's default tablespace.

Try something like this :

```
ALTER USER X QUOTA UNLIMITED ON Y
```

Where X is the USER and Y is the TABLESPACE